# BigQuery - Why Time Travel (FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF) does not work for views?

Tags: google-bigquery

We ran `select count(*) from XXX FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF YYY)`  for a table and a view which selects from the table.  Turned out the result are different.  We changed the timestamp in the time travel expression, it didn't change the result from view, but it did change the result from table.  Could any BQ expert explain why the time travel doesn't work on table?

Comment: Could you tell me why my answer didn't help you? Can you specify more of the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

The [`SYSTEM_TIME AS OF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#query_data_at_a_point_in_time) is used to query historical data from any point within the previous week. This means that it only allows you to check the previous 7 days of full data that is in the table. Your query is trying to select the whole year but this would not be possible since the function only allows you 7 days. And yes, this means that maybe if you deleted something, the result will be different as you have it in the table.

Here I have 11 rows and one is deleted in my table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as PastCount FROM `project.dataset.table` FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

I get this result:

[image]

But when I query my full current table I get the 10 current registers.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as CurrentCount FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

I get this result:

[image]

I created a view to see if the function was not working in views but I got the same result.

```
CREATE VIEW `project.dataset.view` AS
   SELECT COUNT(*) as PastCount FROM `project.dataset.table`  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

I get the next result:

[image]

A [view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) is a virtual table defined by a SQL query. When you create a view, you query it in the same way you query a table. When a user queries the view, the query results contain data only from the tables and fields specified in the query that defines the view. So there wouldn’t be any different result.